# Create basic edition database in Azure with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a basic edition database in my Azure suscription using EF-Code First but I don't find the way to set the edition. Always database is created in standar edition.
I'm using `DbContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists ()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, EF relies on the default parameters when it creates a new database. You can choose to overwrite the default behavior by creating your own database initializer for EF.

```
public class BloggingContextCustomInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<BloggingContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(BloggingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connstrBldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
            connstrBldr.InitialCatalog = "master";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstrBldr.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE [" + context.Database.Connection.Database + "] (EDITION = 'Basic')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BloggingContext>());
            context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
        }
    }
}
```